# Webstorm IDE: Live Template - Accessing the project name

Tags: webstorm, live-templates

I am brand new to Webstorm and live templates. But after doing some researching I can't figure out how to include the project name into a live template. It looks like its easy enough in a regular template ${PROJECT_NAME} but I can't find a $PROJECTNAME$ equivalent for live templates.
Does this not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you want to create file header/top comment block using Live Template rather than create new file using custom File Template?

---

There is no such expression/function for Live Templates -- they are rather targeted for actual code snippets and not for description/documentation blocks.

Live Templates have only two predefined variables: `$END$` and `$SELECTION$`.

All functions that are available in WebStorm that can be used to modify your live template variables are listed here on [official help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/edit-template-variables-dialog.html?search=live%20templ#d384299e220).